# java.lang.VerifyError: ClientProxy overrides final method

Tags: java, automatic-ref-counting, cdi, quarkus

Building a Quarkus project.

Created a class which extends a 3rd party having final methods:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BotService extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

   @Override
   public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
   }

   @Override
   public String getBotUsername() {
     return "something";
   }

   @Override
   public String getBotToken() {
     return System.getenv("token");
   }
}
```

Explicitly adding `quarkus.arc.remove-final-for-proxyable-methods=true` to the application.properties.

When running in dev mode, I see a lot of ignored final methods in log (including the `execute()`):

```
2020-04-19 17:44:23,676 WARN  [io.qua.arc.pro.Methods] (build-25) Final method org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.getMe() is ignored during proxy generation and should never be invoked upon the proxy instance!
2020-04-19 17:44:23,676 WARN  [io.qua.arc.pro.Methods] (build-25) Final method org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.getMeAsync() is ignored during proxy generation and should never be invoked upon the proxy instance!
2020-04-19 17:44:23,676 WARN  [io.qua.arc.pro.Methods] (build-25) Final method org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.getWebhookInfo() is ignored during proxy generation and should never be invoked upon the proxy instance!
2020-04-19 17:44:23,676 WARN  [io.qua.arc.pro.Methods] (build-25) Final method org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.bots.AbsSender.getWebhookInfoAsync() is ignored during proxy generation and should never be invoked upon the proxy instance!
...
```

Everything looks fine, but then it fails with:

```
ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] (main) Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.run(StartupActionImpl.java:83)
        at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:60)
        at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:236)
        at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:39)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:131)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:84)
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:113)
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:408)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize Arc
        at io.quarkus.arc.Arc.initialize(Arc.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.getContainer(ArcRecorder.java:35)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources23.deploy_0(ArcProcessor$generateResources23.zig:72)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources23.deploy(ArcProcessor$generateResources23.zig:36)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:370)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.dubilyer.bot_market.telegram.service.BotService_ClientProxy overrides final method execute.(Lorg/telegram/telegrambots/meta/api/methods/send/SendAudio;)Lorg/telegram/telegrambots/meta/api/objects/Message;
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:757)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:316)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:275)
        at com.dubilyer.bot_market.telegram.service.BotService_Bean.<init>(BotService_Bean.zig:117)
        at io.quarkus.arc.setup.Default_ComponentsProvider.addBeans1(Default_ComponentsProvider.zig:142)
        at io.quarkus.arc.setup.Default_ComponentsProvider.getComponents(Default_ComponentsProvider.zig:38)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.<init>(ArcContainerImpl.java:103)
        at io.quarkus.arc.Arc.initialize(Arc.java:20)
        ... 14 more
```

Any ideas what can cause it and how to avoid it?

Comment: Seems that the `remove-final-for-proxyable-methods` changes the bytecode of the bean class, `BotService`, but for the superclasses. To avoid it you should use composition instead of inheritance, and make BotService delegate the calls to an instance of `TelegramLongPollingBot `

Comment: Upvoted areus' comment to make service that you own, instead of extending library classes. An additional advantage is that you decouple your implementation from the library, giving you freedom to change the library, or the way your are using the library in the future. Additionally, owning the service class allows you to expose only the parts of the library that are interesting to clients within your application, making it easier to enforce your processes, should the need arise.

Comment: Thanks @areus. Resolved in the proposed way.